# In a bivariate normal sample, why is the squared sample correlation Beta distributed?

Tags: distributions, correlation, normal-distribution, beta-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

If $(X_i,Y_i), i = 1, \dots, n$ are independently bivariate normal distributed, with mean $(\mu_x , \mu_y)$ and variances $(\sigma_x^2, \sigma^2_y)$ and correlation coefficient $\rho = 0$.

Denote $T = \frac{\sum_i (X_i - \mu_x)(Y_i - \mu_y)}
{\sqrt{\sum_i (X_i - \mu_x)^2 \sum_j (Y_j - \mu_y)^2}}$ the sample correlation. How can I show $T^2$ is distributed as a Beta distribution?

I know $(X_i - \mu_x)^2$ is a $\chi^2_1$, but I can't figure out what are the relations between distributions and algebra manipulation to show it is beta distributed.

Comment: We [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Using_the_exact_distribution) that density of correlation coefficient $R$ when $\rho=0$ is

$$f_R(r)\propto (1-r^2)^{(n-4)/2}\mathbf1_{|r|<1}$$

By a change of variables $Y=R^2$, it follows that $Y\sim \text{Beta}(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n}{2}-1)$.